# Swift change text of MTMathUILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

i have a problem with my code. I want to change the text of UILabel by tapping the UIbutton. But i get the error "Use of unresolved identifier" in the last line of my code (newLabel.latex = " \(nummer) \\cdot a "). How can i solve this problem ? 
Here is the code

```
  import UIKit
  import iosMath

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var eingabeField: UITextField!
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:115, y:235),
     size:CGSize(width:200, height:100))


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(iosMathVersionNumber)

        let newLabel = MTMathUILabel(frame: rect)
        newLabel.latex = " "
        self.view.addSubview(newLabel)
    }

    @IBAction func berechnen(sender: UIButton) {

        guard let number = eingabeField.text else {
            return
        }

        guard let nummer = Int(number) else {
            return
        }

       newLabel.latex = "\(nummer) \\cdot a "
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant `newLabel` is a **local** variable of the method `viewDidLoad()`.

After that method exits, the variable exists no more. The subview it used to reference remains as a subview of your main view (because you called `addSubview(:)` on it), **but the reference is lost**.

Thus the identifier *newLabel* has no meaning whatsoever in the unrelated function/control action `berechnen(sender:)`. In your program, the **scope** of the constant `newLabel: MTMathUILabel` is limited to the body of the method where it was defined: `viewDidLoad()`.

**Solution:** You must make a stored property and keep the reference to your label there:

```
var mathLabel: MTMathUILabel!

// ...

viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(iosMathVersionNumber)

    self.mathLabel = MTMathUILabel(frame: rect)
    self.mathLabel.latex = " "
    self.view.addSubview(self.mathLabel)
}

@IBAction func berechnen(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let number = eingabeField.text else {
        return
    }
    guard let nummer = Int(number) else {
        return
    }

    self.mathLabel.latex = "\(nummer) \\cdot a "
}
```

*(Using `self.mathLabel` instead of just `mathLabel` for emphasis)*